# Vim error detected

Tags: vimrc, error

**Vim error detected**

Everytime i quit the vim i got this error, it's just pop up in a second.
I already upgrade the vim to the latest version but still got the same error.. How to fix that?

[image]

The error message reads:

```
Error detected while processing function unite#sources#mru#_save[7]..218[7]..219[24]..220:
line    1:
E892: Using a String as a Float
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're seeing refers to a function in the `unite#sources#mru` namespace, which means it's probably in a MRU plug-in for [unite.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim), most probably [neomru.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/neomru.vim).

There's an issue reported there that is very similar to yours: [issue #48: "Vim error: using String as a Float"](https://github.com/Shougo/neomru.vim/issues/48), reporting code that works in NeoVim but breaks in Vim 8.1. That issue was fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/Shougo/neomru.vim/commit/8ad581e0925ecefb94a7d2251803e9b3ba78818e), around 5 months ago.

So, try updating your plug-ins and see if that fixes that issue?

If it doesn't, see if these are indeed the plug-ins you have and try to disable them to confirm whether that solves your issue or not.

If you don't really use those plug-ins (and just got them from copying and pasting from somewhere in the web into your vimrc), consider disabling/removing them, no point in keeping them around if you don't use them...

If you still can't figure it out, you need to post a more detailed question, including more information about your system, which plug-in manager you're using (if any), which plug-ins you have installed, perhaps relevant snippets from your vimrc, etc.

Comment: I tried to remove unite plugin on .vim dir and it's solved the problem. But i still don't know if there's a unite plugin left somewhere since i don't know how that plugin is installed. The plugin comes along with the OS. I'm using NeoBundle

Comment: If removing it from `.vim` solved the problem, then it sounds like you got your answer, right? Was there something else you wanted to get accomplished here?

Comment: I thought unite was deprecated anyway, for denite? Maybe im wrong.

Comment: “Comes along with the OS” huh @Randi ?

Comment: The plugin is pre-installed @D. Ben Knoble

Comment: @Randi what OS?? Never heard of that

Comment: Sorry, i mean Arch base distro (Blackarch linux)